# Partial write enable register bits

Tags: riscv, chisel

I am trying to build a 64-bit register, wherein the write-enable signal can be configured for every flip flop separately. 
Using the **RegEnable** object,

`var test = RegEnable(UInt(5),Bool(true))
test(UInt(0),Bool(false))`

the register can be enabled/disabled as a whole, but is it possible to control each flip flop?

Comment: Using a var for Chisel a variable is probably also a mistake. Chisel variables should typically be val's, and perhaps a handful of Scala variables if necessary can be vars (but most will probably be val).

Answer (score 0):

Instead of partial assignment, we recommend Reg(Vec) or Reg(Bundle).